# How to specify the parameter df in the goodness-of-fit test for a t-copula?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, degrees-of-freedom, copula

I have read the [Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180875/appropriate-number-of-degrees-of-freedom-in-t-copula#), and [Consultation Paper, Article 26, p. 47-48](https://www.eba.europa.eu/documents/10180/724762/EBA-CP-2014-08+CP+on+draft+RTS+on+AMA+assesment.pdf).

I tried to fit a t-copula. I have found the coefficients  `rho.1` and `df` and their standard errors.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(log_returns.x)
df2 <- as.data.frame(log_returns.y)

df = cbind(df1, df2)

t.cop <- tCopula(dim=2)
m <- pobs(as.matrix(df))
fit <- fitCopula(t.cop, m, method='ml')

coef(fit, SE=TRUE)
#        Estimate  Std. Error
# rho.1  0.7872817  0.02087726
# df    13.3784644 13.40797859
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to interpret the coefficient `df` and its standard error (i think it has very large value). I'd like to do the goodness-of-fit test.  I have tried

```
t.copula <- tCopula(dim=2, coef(fit)[1], df=coef(fit)[2])
```

But in my case `df` is not integer. I tried to pass the integer value (`df=13`, `df=3`) instead of `df=coef(fit)[2]`, and setup `df.fixed = TRUE` then the `p_value` and `rho.1` were found.

```
t.copula <- tCopula(dim=2, coef(fit)[1], df=13, df.fixed = TRUE) 
gofCopula(t.copula, rCopula(n, df= 13, t.copula))

# Parametric bootstrap-based goodness-of-fit test of t-copula, dim. d = 2, with 'method'="Sn", 'estim.method'="mpl":

# data:  x
# statistic = 0.016998, parameter.rho.1 = 0.76115, p-value = 0.3891

# There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

gofCopula(t.copula, u, df=3, N=100)
#Parametric bootstrap-based goodness-of-fit test of t-copula, dim. d = 2, with
#        'method'="Sn", 'estim.method'="mpl":

# data:  x
# statistic = 0.012264, parameter.rho.1 = 0.79267, p-value = 0.8465
```

**My questions are:**

a) How to interpret the value of standard error `Std.Error=13.40797859`?

b) How to specify the parameter `df` in order to pass it into the goodness-of-fit test?

**Edit**.

I'm reading the [presentation](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/copulasPowerpoint.pdf) on copula by E. Zivot and try to understand how to use the estimated parameter, `df` (degree of freedom). In the presentation, I have seen the estimated `df.hat` equal to 3.199 (slide 32), later the estimated `df` is 3.5657 (slide 43) and its standard error is `NA`. In both cases `df` aren't the integer.

I have tried the proposed approach in the [presentation](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/copulasPowerpoint.pdf) and setup the `start values` and `lower, upper boundaries`:

```
# fit with t-copula
t.cop <- tCopula(param=0.5, dim=2, df=3) 
start.vals = c(0.5, 3)
names(start.vals) = c("rho.1","df")
fit2 = fitCopula(copula=t.cop, 
                         data=m,
                         method="mpl",
                         start=start.vals, 
                         optim.method="L-BFGS-B",
                         lower=c(-0.99, 2),
                         upper=c(0.99, 10)) # 10 is upper limit of df
coef(fit2, SE=TRUE)
#       Estimate Std. Error
#rho.1  0.785996 0.02546891
#df    10.000000         NA
```

In this case, the upper limit of `df` was obtained and `Std. Error` is `NA`.
The parameter `df` is very important in determining the shape of the distribution. As `df` increases, the t-copula tends to a gaussian copula. See the example [here](https://datascienceplus.com/modelling-dependence-with-copulas/).

I can apply the `round()` function and pass the integer value of `df`:

```
t.copula <- tCopula(dim=2, coef(fit)[1], df=round(df))
```